# Redirect all subfolders but keep files accessible?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, preg-match

I have a website with a public folder in which I host some images.

Let's say that the root folder is "public".
In this folder I have another folder called "images".
In the folder called "images" I have a lots of folders called "1"... "92345678".

I want to create a htaccess rule that will redirect the users from the folders:

```
www.website.com/public/images/
www.website.com/public/images/1
www.website.com/public/images/2
...
www.website.com/public/images/10000001
```

to

```
www.website.com/public/
```

Please give me an option that will work for all sub folders. (Recursive)

I also want to redirect only folders, the images urls should work!

Comment: How will your images be loaded if request is routed to `www.website.com/public/` in browser?

Comment: So... you want to redirect requests for the folder, but leave requests for images as they are?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. I've found a possible solution: RewriteRule ^[SUBDIRECTORY]/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: I've tried this one: RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)\/(.*)$     $2 [L] , but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule in **`/public/images/.htaccess`** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/images/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /public/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: @anubhava according to his question and comments, you will have to include the folder check condition as he wants only folders redirected and not their file content.

Comment: how should I add a condition to redirect only folders and to explude images for example?

Comment: @Pascut before the `RewriteRule` and after the `RewriteBase` add this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`

Answer (score 1):

You must enable rewrite engine and then use rule to redirect from URI's that starting with `/public/image` to `/public`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/public/images.* /public
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
#redirect all subfolders to root and exclude images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ / [R=301,NC,L]
```

Thanks **Mark Shevchenko** and **anubhava** for your help!